# Speak and volumes of speaking

Tags: word-request

When you are speaking to someone and this person is speaking at a low volume and you almost can't hear it, usually you would ask something like this: `Could you please speak louder?`.

What if the situation is the opposite? The person is speaking too loud and you want it to lower the volume? I can only imagine asking like this: `Could you please speak in a lower volume?`. Is there any shorter way to say this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Amadan's answer is the most neutral and polite way to ask, but there are plenty of other things you could say:

- Lower your voice, please.  *--slightly rude, even with the "please"*
- Tone it down!   *--somewhat rude*
- Use your "inside voice".  *--ok to use on small children, very rudely condescending otherwise*
- Do you want the world to know? *--very rude and sarcastic*
- Speak up, the people in [neighboring city] couldn't hear you.  *--very rude and sarcastic*
- Not so loud!  *--somewhat rude*
- Gahhh!  My eardrums!  *--extremely rude*

Comment: I'd personally word the first one as "Could you please lower your voice", as it sounds more polite. My common response is "AAHHH! THE BELLS! THE BELLS!" though.

Comment: The examples you have listed are all *slightly rude*. Could you give me some examples on where it is polite, even understanding, of someone's loud voice, but you want them to lower it?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage, Amadan's answer (or a variation of it) is the polite way to go.  Also the tone of voice in which you make the request is a large factor in just how rude it will be perceived as.  "A little softer, please?" is perfectly fine if said gently but can be rude if spoken as a demand with the "please" just tacked on as an afterthought.

Comment: Sometimes my roommate may be a bit loud at night while I am sleeping (I am fairly susceptible to noise while sleeping), so I want a polite way to remind them that I am both sleeping and that they are a bit loud :).

Comment: @theGreenCabbage, for an informal environment like that, "keep it down out there, please!" (if said with good humor) should be perfectly acceptable.  Alternatively, a pair of earplugs may save you a lot of potential strife.

Comment: Not to brag, but, I wear the best earplugs Amazon can buy, but I am just extremely susceptible to environmental noises while sleeping =P. They're good roommates though! Very understanding. I just don't want to be rude when requesting this.

Answer (score 10):

> Could you please speak more softly?

is the closest parallel to your

> Could you please speak louder?